# AWS SDK Usage using XCode

Tags: xcode, amazon-web-services, xcode8, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

I am a new user of AWS-SDK for C++. I have a question regarding using it through Xcode. I was able to successfully build the AWS-SDK-CPP source and install them. I have 2 folders in my install path: an include directory and a lib directory filled with .dylib files.
    I tried to create a "hello world" test function in Xcode and link it using the files in my install/lib. I am able to build successfully but I am getting the following linker error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libaws-cpp-sdk-core.dylib
Referenced from: /home/myself/Products/Debug/Test_AWS
Reason: image not found
```

I do have the dylibs (file size is > 0). Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,

Balaji V. Iyer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the install path to linker?

Comment: This is better suited as a comment, instead of an answer.

Comment: Hi User2706071, Yes, I have specified DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in the command line but how do I make xcode understand that? Is there a way to set that there?